# How do I seamlessly call MoveWindow on a maximized window in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a C# application that is attempting to create a customizable version of [Windows's Snap](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027324/windows-snap-your-windows) functionality. I primarily use the native functions [MoveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ShowWindowAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633549(v=vs.85).aspx). I also use [GetWindowPlacement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine maximized/normal/minimized state.

I can seamlessly snap a "normal" window around to my user definable frames. The window instantly snaps to new desired position and size.

The problem is when I transition from maximized to normal. If I only call MoveWindow then the window snaps to my desired position and size. However the window still thinks it's "maximized" which causes attempts to re-maximize to fail.

However if I call `ShowWindowAsync(wnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL)` followed by `MoveWindow(wnd, x, y, width, height, true)` it causes the maximized window to animate to it's old position then snap to its new position. This is very jarring and unpleasant. Attempting to flip the call order or use `ShowWindow` instead of `ShowWindowAsync` does not help.

The answer to this question *might* be to disable the animation. I have not found a clean way to do that.

Comment: Hmm, Aero Snap does not maximize a window.  It is just a positioning aid that uses MoveWindow, any resemblance to a maximized window is purely accidental.  Get ahead by not needing GetWindowPlacement.

Comment: Not quite true! You can use Win+Left and Win+Right to cycle between left-half, right-half, and "normal". However you can also use Win+Up and Win+Down to maximize or minimize. Which do set the proper states.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

The fix is to call `SetWindowPlacement` instead of `MoveWindow`. `SetWindowPlacement` takes a `WINDOWPLACEMENT` structure which allows setting both position/size and `showCmd` state at the same time.